# Docker compose yml описание

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Есть такой [образ](https://github.com/Evild67/docker-compose-lemp) для быстрого развертывания LEMP

```
version: '2' 
  services:   
      nginx:
          image: evild/alpine-nginx:1.9.15-openssl
          container_name: lemp_nginx
          restart: always
          links:
              - php
          volumes:
              - ./public:/var/www/html/:ro
              - ./nginx/conf/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf/nginx.conf:ro
              - ./nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d:ro
          ports:
              - 80:80
              - 443:443   
      php:
          image: evild/alpine-php:7.0.6
          container_name: lemp_php
          restart: always
          volumes:
              - ./html:/var/www/html
          depends_on:
              - db
          links:
              - db
          environment:
              - DB_NAME=lemp_bdd
              - TABLE_PREFIX=lemp_
              - DB_HOST=lemp
              - DB_PASSWORD=password   
      db:
          image: mariadb:latest
          container_name: lemp_mariadb
          restart: always
          volumes:
              - db-data:/var/lib/mysql
          environment:
              - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password 
    volumes:   
        db-data:
            driver: local
```

Есть файл docker-compose yml, описание выше.

Непонятны такие моменты:

1.Образ nginx

```
volumes:
   - ./public:/var/www/html/:ro
   - ./nginx/conf/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf/nginx.conf:ro
   - ./nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d:ro
ports:
   - 80:80
   - 443:443
```

1.1 Звчем в конце строк **:ro** - что это значит?

1.2 Звчем нужен 443 порт?

2.Образ php

```
volumes:
   - ./public:/var/www/html
environment:
   - DB_NAME=lemp_bdd
   - TABLE_PREFIX=lemp_
   - DB_HOST=lemp
   - DB_PASSWORD=password


2.1 Зачем в образе php указывать еще раз корень ./public:/var/www/html
2.2 Почему переменные базы лежат в образе php, а не db?
2.3 Переменные по базе(DB_NAME, TABLE_PREFIX и т.д) - это уже установленные в образе? То есть чтобы поменять имя базы и прочее, мне нужно залазить внутрь контейнера? Или эти данные будут браться для создания базы с такими параметрами?
2.4 Почему - DB_HOST=lemp, обычно localhost или ip или это внутри контейнера в hosts прописано 127.0.0.1 lemp?
```

2.Образ db

```
volumes:
    - db-data:/var/lib/mysql
environment:
     - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
```

3.1 - db-data:/var/lib/mysql - для чего эта строчка?

3.2 - - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password  - это рутовый пароль, но в образе **php** нет DB_USERNAME=, то есть опять нужно заходить в контейнер и создавать пользователя?

```
volumes:   
   db-data:
       driver: local
```

Для чего этот блок?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1.1 Звчем в конце строк :ro - что это значит?

Read-only: контейнер не может изменить файлы в точках монтирования, но может их читать. Это является хорошей практикой и может защитить от некоторых (но не очень вероятных) атак.

> 1.2 Звчем нужен 443 порт?

HTTPS шифрует полностью весь поток данных, и, таким образом, является принципиально отличным протоколом (хоть внутри и передаются ровно те же данные), поэтому его необходимо обрабатывать на отдельном порту. По умолчанию для HTTPS используется 443.

> 2.2 Почему переменные базы лежат в образе php, а не db?

Потому что это не "переменные базы", а данные, необходимые для авторизации в базе данных

> 2.4 Почему - DB_HOST=lemp, обычно localhost или ip или это внутри контейнера в hosts прописано 127.0.0.1 lemp?

Потому что 127.0.0.1 в контейнере - это сам контейнер, а база лежит в другом контейнере/на другой машине, на который(-ую) можно сослаться как lemp (возможно, здесь просто ошибка именования, и имедось в виду lemp_mariadb)

> 3.1 - db-data:/var/lib/mysql - для чего эта строчка?

"смонтировать директорию db-data, находящуюся на одном уровне с docker-compose.yml, в качестве /var/lib/mysql внутри контейнера"

Comment: Скажите а с базой как нужно работать? база должна быть внутри контейнера, тогда как накатывать миграции?

Comment: @ruslik а разве при накатке миграций есть разница, где расположена база?

Comment: так а база где располагается внутри контейнера или нет?

Comment: @ruslik у вас в docker-compose объявлен контейнер db - очевидно, что это именно оно